# How to synchronise dark/light mode between Docusaurus and MaterialUI?

Tags: material-ui, docusaurus

I am new Docusaurus user, trying to synchronise Docusaurus dark/light mode with MaterialUI's dark/light mode. For example, when the toggle switch is changed from light to dark mode in Docusaurus then dark mode should be activated in MaterialUI.

My approach so far has been to swizzle Docusaurus `ColorModeToggle` via
wrapping. From the wrapped `ColorModeToggle` I retrieve a function stored in a React context to toggle the light/dark theme in MaterialUI. Within the swizzled `Root` I use the react context provider which, in turn, wraps a MaterialUI `ThemeProvider`. For further details I have included the code below.

However, when I browse my site, I get the following error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
> repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
> prevent infinite loops.

Has anyone else managed to synchronise Docusaurus light/dark theme with
MaterialUI?

The swizzled ColorModeToggle

```js
import React from "react";
import ColorModeToggle from "@theme-original/ColorModeToggle";
import { useToggleTheme } from "@site/src/components/MuiTheme";

export default function ColorModeToggleWrapper(props) {
  console.log("<ColorModeToggleWrapper> properties = " + JSON.stringify(props));

  // "value" holds docusaurus color theme. Either "light" or "dark"
  const { value } = props;
  const muiToggle = useToggleTheme();

  console.log("Docusaurus theme = " + value);
  console.log("MUI theme dark = " + muiToggle());

  return (
    <>
      <ColorModeToggle {...props} />
    </>
  );
}
```

The React Context

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const CustomThemeContext = React.createContext({ toggleTheme: () => {} });

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiListItemText: {
      styleOverrides: {
        primary: {
          color: "orange",
        },
        secondary: {
          color: "purple",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  palette: {
    mode: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: "hsl(8,71%,28%)" /* burgundy mapped to link */,
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "hsl(61,78%,26%)" /* brown */,
    },
  },
});

const lightTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiListItemText: {
      styleOverrides: {
        primary: {
          color: "aqua",
        },
        secondary: {
          color: "grey",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  palette: {
    mode: "light",
    primary: {
      main: "hsl(8,10%,18%)" /* burgundy mapped to link */,
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "hsl(61,18%,26%)" /* brown */,
    },
  },
});

export function CustomThemeProvider({ children }) {
  const [dark, setDark] = React.useState(false);

  function toggleTheme() {
    console.log("toggleTheme :: from dark = " + dark);
    if (dark === true) {
      setDark(false);
    } else {
      setDark(true);
    }
  }

  const theme = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (dark === true) {
      return createTheme(darkTheme);
    }
    return createTheme(lightTheme);
  }, [dark]);

  return (
    <CustomThemeContext.Provider value={toggleTheme}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
    </CustomThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useToggleTheme() {
  const context = useContext(CustomThemeContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "useCustomThemeContext must be used within an CustomThemeProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
}
```

The Root component

```js
import React from "react";
import { CustomThemeProvider } from "@site/src/components/MuiTheme";
import App from "@site/src/components/App";

export default function Root({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <CustomThemeProvider>
        <App children={children}></App>
      </CustomThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

The App component

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  return <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved why the error message was happening. I was calling the `toggleTheme` function directly during rendering. Further details are explained [here](https://typeofnan.dev/fix-the-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error-in-react/)

I updated the `ColorModeToggleWrapper` to be as listed below. This uses `useEffect` to monitor change of the Docusaurus value property. When the value changes then `useEffect` toggles the Material-UI theme using a reference to the function stored in the react context.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ColorModeToggle from "@theme-original/ColorModeToggle";
import { useToggleTheme } from "@site/src/components/MuiTheme";

export default function ColorModeToggleWrapper(props) {
  // extract the docusaurus theme from the component properties
  const { value } = props;

  // get the toggleTheme function from the context
  const toggleTheme = useToggleTheme();

  // whenever the theme changes in docusaurus trigger the change
  // in MaterialUI by calling the callback function stored in the react
  // context
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Docusaurus theme changed to = " + value);
    console.log("Synching theme change with MaterialUI");

    toggleTheme();
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <>
      <ColorModeToggle {...props} />
    </>
  );
}
```

This solved the error detailed in the question. Now I just need to ensure that the initial starting state of the Material-UI theme matches the initial state of the Docusaurus theme......

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the new MUI [CSS theme variables](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/overview/) to keep your themes synchronized, including light/dark mode, and avoid having to create a custom context. [This guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/migration/) includes many of the steps you'll need to follow.

First, swizzle the `ColorModeToggle` and add the `useColorScheme` hook to notify MUI whenever Docusaurus toggles the color mode:

```js
import { useColorScheme } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ColorModeToggleWrapper(props): {
  // Get the MUI hook
  const { setMode } = useColorScheme();

  // Extract the docusaurus theme from the component properties
  const { value } = props;

  // Whenever the theme changes in docusaurus, trigger the change in MUI
  useEffect(() => {
    setMode(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <>
      <ColorModeToggle {...props} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Then, swizzle the `Root` component and wrap its children in a `CssVarsProvider` component:

```js
import { experimental_extendTheme as extendTheme, Experimental_CssVarsProvider as CssVarsProvider, getInitColorSchemeScript } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';

const theme = extendTheme({
  colorSchemes: {
    light: {
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: '#ff5252',
        },
        // ...
      },
    },
    dark: {
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: '#52ffff',
        },
        // ...
      },
    },
  },
  // ...other properties
});

function Root({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      {getInitColorSchemeScript()}
      <CssVarsProvider theme={theme}>{children}</CssVarsProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

A few notes:

- The addition of `getInitColorSchemeScript()` [prevents dark mode flickering](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/migration/#3-prevent-dark-mode-flickering-in-server-side-applications)
- The theme now uses the new [colorSchemes](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/migration/#custom-theme) node

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Unfortunately, the flickering still happens in dark mode in my case :/